# Editing a Heatmap in Python via Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, heatmap

I am trying to plot a heatmap and I found this code online although I am having some difficulty using it. I am trying to to do hierarchical clustering and test gene methylation of one another, I made a DataFrame using pandas where I have Betavalues and Genes as separate columns (df4). Later I converted it to a matrix like scipy prefers.I tried running the code with my matrix but it gave me a value error saying "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'tAKR'", I already removed the N/A and anything that is not a gene or a valid Beta value. 
I was wondering if you may have any suggestions? 
Below I have attached a picture of what my dataframe looks like before changing into a matrix. [![enter image description here][1]][1]
    import scipy
    import pylab
    import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch

```
df5 = df4.as_matrix()
# Generate random features and distance matrix.
x = scipy.rand(40)
D = scipy.zeros([40,40])
for i in range(40):
    for j in range(40):
        D[i,j] = abs(x[i] - x[j])

# Compute and plot first dendrogram.
fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.09,0.1,0.2,0.6])
Y = sch.linkage(df5, method='centroid')
Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y, orientation='right')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])

# Compute and plot second dendrogram.
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.71,0.6,0.2])
Y = sch.linkage(df5, method='single')
Z2 = sch.dendrogram(Y)
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])

# Plot distance matrix.
axmatrix = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.1,0.6,0.6])
idx1 = Z1['leaves']
idx2 = Z2['leaves']
D = D[idx1,:]
D = D[:,idx2]
im = axmatrix.matshow(D, aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=pylab.cm.YlGnBu)
axmatrix.set_xticks([])
axmatrix.set_yticks([])

# Plot colorbar.
axcolor = fig.add_axes([0.91,0.1,0.02,0.6])
pylab.colorbar(im, cax=axcolor)
fig.show()
fig.savefig('dendrogram.png')
```

Comment: Perhaps the library [heatmapcluster](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/heatmapcluster) is something you could use.

Comment: Hi Thank you but I get an error when  I tried running the program saying no package called heatmapcluster

Comment: You have to install it.  The package is on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), so you should be able to [install it with `pip`](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#installing-from-pypi).

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in an out-of-the-box solution if you're not comfortable with this. Check out `seaboarn`'s [`clustermap`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html), which accepts `pandas` data frames as inputs.

```
>>> import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
>>> flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
>>> flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
>>> g = sns.clustermap(flights)
```

I am not affiliated with Seaborn.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion unfortunately seaborn seems to be great at graphing and not very good at sorting through my data that may have similar genes in each case but must remain separate for identification purposes, which is what I was told scipy as a hierarchical clustering can do.

Comment: Seaborn sits on top of the `scipy` code. It produces examples that exactly match the intent expressed by your image. If you need, you can specify a metric and linkage method, but `clustermap` does the same thing as the code above.

Comment: Can you explain specifically what you see as lacking?

Comment: so I have  a lot of files with different cases with genes that have distinct/similar beta values some of the genes are present in one case but not always in the other. I am hoping to use the code I posted above to make a large heatmap in which it will order the genes that are present throughout my cases but continue adding the new genes that aren't present in say case 1 or 2. Furthermore, I can't just append all the cases together or else I will lose the ability to distinguish which genes/beta values came from which case.

Comment: In addition, to organize the data I used dictionaries to label say case 1 with its distinct genes and beta values, i know its bad form to shove a dataframe into a dictionary but I found that it produced the results that I needed, in terms of allowing me to distinguish beta and genes associated with individual cases. The next step that I was  hoping for was to graph the different cases on the y axis and the genes on the x axis, of course not all of them have the same genes present hence why I am trying to figure out that code.

Comment: Furthermore, the X0 indicates the genes selected from each case, I am using keys to select from my dictionary the cases I want to pull.  I hope that explains things ?  thanks again for the help!